# Sublime Text 3 snippet with two underscores not working

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublimetext-snippet

I created this snippet for ST3 which should be triggered by typing two underscores:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
<?php echo $this->__('${1:TEXT'); ?>
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>__</tabTrigger>
</snippet>
```

Whenever I type the two underscores followed by `TAB`, the two underscores simply diappear and nothing more happens. Any idea what could be wrong here? I had this working before already...

Comment: You have two syntax error: use `\$this` instead of `$this` and `'${1:TEXT}'` instead of `'${1:TEXT'.`

Comment: Oh man, you're right - thanks a lot! It was just the missing closing `}`.